# Make Django's ORM use (*) for selecting all field in a database request

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

Is it possible to make Django use the asterisk (*) for selecting all fields in a table instead of listing all individual fields?

E.g. instead of:

```
SELECT "photos_photo"."id", "photos_photo"."user_id", "photos_photo"."tags"
    FROM "photos_photo"
    WHERE "photos_photo"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
    FROM "photos_photo"
    WHERE "photos_photo"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I know, using the asterisk *in general* is rather bad practice, but in our case we need all fields and it results in a better performance.

Comment: Interesting question. I do remember a talk (sorry, don't have a link) where it was recommended that the leading `"photos_photo".` be left off when only one table was involved in the query.

Comment: I think, that would be an improvement.